# Windows XAML control with CacheMode=BitMapCache shows black screen

Tags: xaml, silverlight, windows-store

I have a map control

> < Maps:MapControl x:Name="_instiMap" CacheMode="BitMapCache" />

This shows a black screen on opening the app.

When I just have

> < Maps:MapControl x:Name="_instiMap" />

the map is rendered fine. I added bitmap cache for performance improvements, since navigation transitions were lagging with map control. What do I do to enable bitmapcache and still render the map properly? If not, how can I improve map performance?

Comment: Is this question still relevant for you?